# How to patch objects with "autospec" set to True?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching, pytest-mock

I have the following toy class:

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def get_operator(self):
        answer = input("Multiply? ")
        if answer == "y":
            return "multiply"

    def multiply(self, y):
        if self.get_operator() == "multiply":
            return self.x * y
```

The following test (using pytest) will throw an error:

```py
def test_multiply_is_called(mocker):
    multiply = mocker.patch("package.module.MyClass.multiply", return_value=1, autospec=True)
    my_instance = MyClass(2)
    my_instance.multiply(3)
    multiply.assert_called_once()  # no error whatever autospec is equal to (True or False)
    multiply.assert_called_with(3)  # no error only if autospec=False
```

> TypeError: Can't use 'autospec' with create=True

It gets even less clear when trying to mock Python built-in function `input`:

```py
def test_input_is_called_once(mocker):
    input = mocker.patch("package.module.input", return_value="y", autospec=True)
    my_instance = MyClass(2)
    my_instance.get_operator()
    input.assert_called_once()  # no error only if autospec=False
```

> E       AssertionError: expected call not found.
> E       Expected: multiply(3)
> E       Actual: multiply(<package.module.MyClass object at 0x0000022A4BEEFD00>, 3)

I get that mocking with `autospec=True` is a recommended practice, but, obviously, I have a wrong understanding of how it works, despite having read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40520016/11246056) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35921144/11246056), for instance.

Could someone please clarify this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are actually two unrelated problems.
The first problem stems from the fact that with `autospec=False`, the call `my_instance.multiply(3)` just boils down to a call of the mock with the argument 3 without any checks (e.g. a simple function call).
If you use `autospec=True`, however, the method `multiply` is bound to `my_instance` as in the real call, and called as a method, with `my_instance` as the first (`self`) argument. So to get it to work you need:

```py
def test_multiply_is_called(mocker):
    multiply = mocker.patch("package.module.MyClass.multiply", return_value=1, autospec=True)
    my_instance = MyClass(2)
    my_instance.multiply(3)
    multiply.assert_called_with(my_instance, 3)
```

The second case is different, and I have to admit that I'm not completely clear how it works correctly with `autospec=False`. The problem is that `input` is not bound to the module, but it is a global import (from `builtins`), and so it is created as a new mock object without the knowledge of the actual built-in function. In this case, `autospec` will not work because of missing information. This can be fixed by mocking the built-in function instead:

```py
def test_input_is_called_once(mocker):
    input = mocker.patch("builtins.input", return_value="y", autospec=True)
    my_instance = MyClass(2)
    my_instance.get_operator()
    input.assert_called_once()
```

This works for both `autospec=True` and `autospec=False`. As far as I understand, with `autospec=False` it works because a mock is created for a local `input` function, and that is then actually used in the call. From my point of view, the correct way for mocking `input` is to mock `builtins.input`, anyway.